# Inserting textboxes in Word with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, textbox

So far, haven't found answer to this on Stack.  I'm programmatically adding sections to a document, and each section has to have a textbox.  Here's the code as it stands:

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
   {
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section = oDoc.Sections.Add();
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape textbox =   

        Doc.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.
        MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationVertical, 575, 50, 30, 100);

   }
```

Sorry about the formatting.  The result is a document with 25 pages, but all the textframes are piled on top of each other, on the first page.

Comment: It seems you are giving the exact same values for the `left` and `top` parameter in the function `AddTextbox` on each iteration of the loop. The parameters are as follows: `AddTextbox(Orientation, Left, Top, Width, Height)` so you probably need to programmatically change the values for `Left` and `Top` as needed.

Comment: you are adding the TextBox directly to the Doc. I'm not an expert here, but wouldn't you want to add them to the Section? I would expect a pile of 25 things in the document based upon that code. You will have to probably format the Section to give it its' own page.

Answer (score 0):

just add these two lines before closing tag of loop

```
// this line will help you to break the page...

oDoc.Words.Last.InsertBreak(word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);

// this line will help to go to the next page and add textbox...

oDoc.PageSetup.Application.GoForward();
```

this works for me :)